# The addOnScrollListener for my RecyclerView not working as expected

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I want to know when I am at the bottom of my recycler view but I can't get why the recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) is always returning true even if I am at the bottom of the Recycler View.

The recycler view is inside a CoordinatorLayout with an AppBarLayout.

You have the Kotlin code and the XML code for the bigger picture

Thank you.

[image]

```java
getDataBinding().shipmentRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        Log.e(TAG,
            "onScrollStateChanged 1: This is the bottom shipmentRecyclerView $newState <> ${RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE} ${
                recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)
            }")
        if (!getDataBinding().shipmentRecyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged 2: This is the bottom shipmentRecyclerView")
            if (viewModel.currentPage.get()!! < viewModel.totalPages.get()!!) {
                viewModel.getShipmentByPage(
                    viewModel.currentPage.get()!! + 1,
                    viewModel.request.get()
                )
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.technifyit.jibheli.presentation.main.fragment.search.SearchViewModel" />
    </data>

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:umanoPanelHeight="0dp"
        app:umanoShadowHeight="@dimen/margin_4dp"
        tools:context=".presentation.main.fragment.search.SearchFragment">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/shipment_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_12dp"
                android:clipToPadding="true"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:shipment_adapter="@{viewModel}" />

        


            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/dark_color_purple"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                    ...........
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/dark_color_purple"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:title="">

.........

          </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom_web_page_browser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_rounded_top"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/grey_clair">

            <com.technifyit.jibheli.presentation.customView.MontserratBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/url_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_6dp"
                android:text="@string/activity_item_details_send_request_button_text"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_color_purple"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_size_sign_up"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/close"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/use_link_image_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/close"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/close" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_24dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_24dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_close_gold"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_color_purple"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_native"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <com.technifyit.jibheli.presentation.customView.MontserratBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/use_link_image_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_rounded_left_only_no_icon"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_color_purple"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_check_native"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_6dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                android:text="@string/select"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:drawableTint="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_4dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/close">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/no_item_found_suggested_layout"
                        layout="@layout/no_item_found_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/requested_shipments_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6dp"
                        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:requested_shipment_adapter="@{viewModel}" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/requested_trip_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6dp"
                        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:requested_trip_adapter="@{viewModel}" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can you provide full layout? I'm seeing `</ScrollView>` but no opening tag.

Comment: I think the main issue is that you have `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView`, and it's not `RecyclerView` scrolling but `ScrollView`

Comment: I wasn't able to put all the code because i exceeded the 30000 char but i tried to shrink it a little bit and updated it now, Thank you.

Comment: The scroll view is in other layout, and also the listener for the recycler view works and changes when you scroll but the problem is that it can't get when it is in the bottom of the recycler view it self

Comment: I built simplified version of above code and got this result in logcat:
```E/MainActivity: onScrollStateChanged 1: This is the bottom shipmentRecyclerView 1 <> 0 true
E/MainActivity: onScrollStateChanged 1: This is the bottom shipmentRecyclerView 2 <> 0 true
E/MainActivity: onScrollStateChanged 1: This is the bottom shipmentRecyclerView 0 <> 0 false
E/MainActivity: onScrollStateChanged 2: This is the bottom shipmentRecyclerView```

Comment: So in my case it successfuly detected that I reached bottom (`onScrollStateChanged 2`), so if it doesn't work for you there must be some other issue.

Comment: I can tell that you are running it in an activity, but i am running it in a fragment, That's the only difference that i  am seeing and i don't think that can lead to a problem with a listener, That's weird

Comment: Shouldn't really matter on layout level. My guesses (since I can't debug whole code) would be the following: 1. ScrollView steals scrolling from RecyclerView. 2. There is some bug-prone configuration of the views in fragment code. 3. Some  issue with specific phone. You should try to build simplified version and check if that works or not. If it does, add other features and check at which point it breaks.

Comment: Thank you for you analysis, i did find an other solution that got the job done, so maybe it would be helpful for any one later on, Thank you  xinaiz

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response, i did find a solution by adding to my recycler view in xml
`addOnScrolledToBottomListener="@{viewModel}"` and then in the bindingAdapter

```
        @BindingAdapter("addOnScrolledToBottomListener")
        fun addOnScrolledToBottomListener(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewModel: SearchViewModel) {
            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object :
                RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                    if (recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (viewModel.currentPage.get()!! < viewModel.totalPages.get()!!) {
                            viewModel.getShipmentByPage(
                                viewModel.currentPage.get()!! + 1,
                                viewModel.request.get()
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

        }`


and like that it worked like a charm, Thank you @xinaiz for your help
```